# How to validate a common error div for dynamic fields in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I am trying to add multiple images. I have applied a validation to image (accepts only .jpg, .jpeg files).

When I click on submit, it validates only 1st file and not validating other files. I want to give error messages for every file when the file format is not valid.

[Snapshot of adding images. Validating 1st file only but not 4th file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2D15.jpg)

HTML code:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="form-label"><strong>Product Image</strong>
  </label>
  <span class="tips"></span>
  <div class="controls">
    <input type="file" id="file" name="uploadFileForImage" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div id="imageError" class="validationError" style="color:red"></div>
</div>
<div id="productImageDivId"></div>
<div class="form-group">
  <div id="productImageAddMoreButtonId">
    <button onclick="addFileConrol('productImageDivId','productImageAddMoreButtonId','uploadFileForImage',1)"
            class="btn btn-primary">Add More Files
    </button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 table-responsive">
    <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3">
      <div class="pull-right">
        <button class="btn btn-info m-b-10" onclick="return validateProductForm()">Submit</button>
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger m-b-10">Reset</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Validate Function on submit:

```
function validateProductForm() {

  var z = $('#addProductForm').parsley('validate');
  var moreFile = String($("#moreFile").val()).toLowerCase();
  var file = String($("#file").val()).toLowerCase();

  if (file != "") {
    if (!hasExtension('file', ['.jpg', '.gif', '.png', '.jpeg', '.bmp', '.JPG', '.GIF', '.PNG', '.JPEG', '.BMP'])) {
      $("#imageError").html("Please select a valid file, Valid file formats are .jpg, .gif, .png, .jpeg, .bmp");
      z = false;
    } else {
      $("#imageError").html("");
    }
  } else {
    $("#imageError").html("");
  }

  if (moreFile != "") {
    if (!hasExtension('moreFile', ['.jpg', '.gif', '.png', '.jpeg', '.bmp', '.JPG', '.GIF', '.PNG', '.JPEG', '.BMP'])) {
      $("#moreError").html("Please select a valid file, Valid file formats are .jpg, .gif, .png, .jpeg, .bmp");
      z = false;
    } else {
      $("#moreError").html("");
    }
  } else {
    $("#moreError").html("");
  }

  return false;
}
```

Common function for Add more file -

```
function addFileConrol(fileCtrlAppendDivId,AddMoreButtonDivId,fileName,index){
  //alert("file name : "+fileName);
  var html="<div id=\'"+fileCtrlAppendDivId+index+"\' class=\'form-group\'>"
           +"\n  <div class=\'controls\' style=\'width: 87%; float: left;\'>"
           +" <input type=\'file\' id=\'moreFile\' class=\'form-control\' name=\'"+fileName+"\'>"
           +"\n  </div>"
           +"\n  <div class=\'controls\'>"
           +"\n    <div><a class=\'delete btn btn-danger\' onclick=\'hideDiv(\""+fileCtrlAppendDivId+index+"\")\'\n            style=\' margin-left: 3px; width: 55px;height: 43px;\'><i class=\'fa fa-times-circle\'\n                                                                    style=\'margin-left: -4px; margin-top: 6px;\'></i>\n    </a></div>"
           +"\n    <div id=\'moreError\' class=\'validationError\' name=\'"+fileName+"\' style=\'color:red\'></div>"
           +"\n  </div>"
           +"\n</div>";
  $('#'+fileCtrlAppendDivId).append(html);
  html="<button onclick='addFileConrol(\""+fileCtrlAppendDivId+"\",\""+AddMoreButtonDivId+"\",\""+fileName+"\","+(index+1)+")' class='btn btn-primary'>Add More Files</button>";
  $('#'+AddMoreButtonDivId).html(html);
}
```

I want to use `id="moreError"` (defined in `addFileControl()` function) for every file validation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Improved formatting. Question is still a bit messy

Comment: Did you copy this code from somebody?

Comment: IDs must be unique to the entire document, so if you have multiple `id="moreError"` your code will not work.

Comment: Thanks. Question is i want to add multiple images.if i select other file format then .jpg, .jpeg, it will give me an error . so it is validating only 1st & 2nd file but not others. i want id="moreError" to validate each file i am adding. please refer snapshot for more clarification. @FrankvanWijk

Comment: No. it's my own code @Refilon

Comment: id="moreError" is unique. addFileConrol() is a common method to add multiple images. so every file added is using id="moreFile" & file validation error for each file is using id="moreError". @MikeMcCaughan

Comment: If each file has its own `id="moreError"`, and they are all added to the same div (as is indicated by your `addFileControl()` method, then they are not unique to the **entire document**. It manifests itself as only the first file being validated because it only finds the first `id="moreError"` and prints the error message there.

Comment: you are correct @MikeMcCaughan . I have solved it by making that id dynamic. It's working well now.